# Rails Sitemap Generator Uploading to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sitemap, aws-sdk

Trying to generate a sitemap and uploading it to my current existing bucket in Amazon's S3, however, I'm getting

```
Excon::Errors::Forbidden: Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
```

This is my `sitemap.rb` file

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "http://www.example.com"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.public_path = 'tmp/sitemaps/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_host = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/#{ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']}/"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  add about_path
  add landing_index_path
  add new_user_session_path, priority: 0.0

  Trip.find_each do |trip|
    add trip_path(trip.slug), lastmod: trip.updated_at
  end
end
```

I have this in my `s3.rb` file

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id      => Rails::AWS.config['access_key_id'],
      :aws_secret_access_key  => Rails::AWS.config['secret_access_key'],
      :region                 => 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = Rails::AWS.config['bucket_name']
end
```

Would someone be able to know what the issue is with this?

Answer (score 1):

My working config (which I use in heroku) is a little different than yours, here is what I have:

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = 'http://example.com'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.public_path = 'tmp/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.adapter = SitemapGenerator::S3Adapter.new(fog_provider: 'AWS', fog_directory: 'sitemap-bucket')
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_host = "http://#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com/"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_path = 'sitemaps/'
```

I don't use a S3.rb, instead, I set the following environment variables:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
FOG_DIRECTORY
FOG_REGION
```

I used the tutorial in here: https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/wiki/Generate-Sitemaps-on-read-only-filesystems-like-Heroku

I hope it helps!

Comment: I'm using carrierwave, which is similar to what I have.

Comment: Have you tried to replace your sitemaps_host/sitemaps_path for something like the one I pasted?

`SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_host = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/#{ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']}/"
`

For something like this:

`SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_host = "http://#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com/"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_path = 'sitemaps/'`

Comment: Actually, when I tried changing the path, I get this: `Pinging with URL 'http://.s3.amazonaws.com/sitemap.xml.gz':`
`Ping failed for Google: #<OpenURI::HTTPError: 400 Bad Request> (URL http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=http%3A%2F%2F.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fsitemap.xml.gz)`

Comment: Maybe instead of `ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']` you should use something like `config.fog_directory  = Rails::AWS.config['bucket_name']`?

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing a similar error:

```
In '/app/tmp/':
rake aborted!
ArgumentError:  is not a recognized provider
```

Going off the help of renatolond's answer above, this is the configuration that worked for me. The key is to make sure that all of your variables, such as "fog_region:" actually match up to valid values. Do not blindly copy + paste configuration credentials.

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "https://yourwebsitename.com"

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.public_path = 'tmp/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.adapter = SitemapGenerator::S3Adapter.new(
  fog_provider: 'AWS',
  aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  fog_directory: ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
  fog_region: ENV['AWS_REGION'])

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_host = "http://{ENV['S3_BUCKET']}.s3.amazonaws.com/"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_path = 'sitemaps/'
```

Comment: Cheers John - I was puling my hair out trying to get this to work. Setting up all the AWS stuff in the adapter instead worked first time! Lifesaver!